# How to execute a java file by shell script

Tags: java, shell

How to execute a java file by shell script?

Comment: [Windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) or [*nix](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's packed up as a jar:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

If it is a class file:

```
java myClassFile
```

If it is a jar file:

```
java -jar myJarFile.jar
```

See:

- Tutorial: http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/running-an-executable-jar-from-command-line/
- Official documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Answer (score 2):

`java com.foo.Boo`

Comment: To compile the .java File --> "javac javafile.java" (generates javafile.class). To run it --> "java javafile"

Answer (score 1):

All the answers only show the terminal commands to compile and run .java files but not the shell script to do so.

Below is the shell script. Let's call it compileRunJava.sh

```
javac $1
java ${1%.java}
```

You may need to giv terminal the permission to run your script -

```
$ sudo chmod 754 compileRunJava.sh
```

Let's say your .java file is Hello.java. To run the script, cd to the directory where you have Hello.java. Run the below command -

```
$ /path/to/shell/script/directory/compileRunJava.sh Hello.java
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nifty little trick after if you're using java 11 or more. To execute a single class you can do the following.

**PS: This is for unix based systems, IDK about windows.**

**Step 1:** Create A File by executing the command

```
$ touch hello
```

**Step 2:** Add code to the file by using `vi` or any other text editor. My code looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source <GET_YOUR_JAVA_VERSION>

public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Notice the shebang line. That is required.

**Step 3:** Make that file executable by executing the following command.

```
$ chmod +x hello
```

**Step 4:** Execute the file

```
$ ./hello
Hello
```

This is a great thing that is introduced after java 11. You can read about it more over [here](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330#Shebang_files).